# Botón submit en tira flotante no funciona

Tags: php

Tengo un botón flotante el cual despliega opciones: abrir caja, cerrar caja, e/s e imprimir respectivamente.

Pero tengo el problema de que todos los botones imprimen, es decir envían el `submit` del formulario:

```html
<form method="POST" action="views/modules/caja/reportecaja.php" >
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align: center;height: 10px;">DATOS DE SESION</h5>  
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <label>CAJERO.:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <input type="hidden" name="nombre" value="<?php if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){echo $_SESSION['username'];}?>"/>
                            <label><?php if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){echo $_SESSION['username'];}?></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <label>HORA INICIO:<?php if (isset($_SESSION['inicio'])){echo $_SESSION['inicio'];}?></label>
                        </div> 
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <label>HORA FIN:<?php  date_default_timezone_set("America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires");$horaactual=date("H:i:s"); echo $horaactual;?></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <label> Efectivo:</label>
                            <label id="subtotal"></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <label>Cambio:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="cambio" placeholder="QUEDA EN CAJA" id="cambio"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <label>Total</label>
                            <label id="total"></label>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div> 
    </div>
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align: center;height: 10px;">LISTADO DE MOVIMIENTOS DEL TURNO</h5>  
                </div>
             <div class="card-body">
                <div class="table-responsive" >                  
                  <table id="resumen" class="table table-hover">
                    <title>Comprobantes</title>
                    <thead class="thead-dark">

                    </thead>
                    <tfoot>
                      <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                      </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                    <tbody>

                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>  
          </div>
          <div class="contenedor">
            <button class="botonF11" id="opciones" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="left" data-content="OPCIONES" style="color: black;">
              <span><i class="fas fa-tasks"></i></span>
            </button>
            <button class="btn2 botonF2" id="abrircaja" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="left" data-content="ABRIR CAJA" style="color: black;">
              <span><i class="fas fa-lock-open"></i></span>
            </button>
            <button class="btn2 botonF3" id="cerrarcaja" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="left" data-content="CERRAR CAJA" style="color: black;">
              <span><i class="fas fa-lock"></i></span>
            </button>
            <button class="btn2 botonF4" id="es" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="left" data-content="ENTRADA/SALIDA" style="color: black;">
              <span><i class="fas fa-dollar-sign"></i></span>
            </button>
            <button class="btn2 botonF5" id="imprimir"  data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="left" data-content="IMPRIMIR" style="color: black;">
              <span><i class="fas fa-print"></i></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

De que manera puedo incluir un botón y que solo este llame al `form`.

Trabajo con FPDF.

Comment: Pueden ser muchas cosas...Si trabajas con PHP y nos pones el HTML poco vamos a poder mirar, quiza se algo de JS? no tienes el ningun submit, quiza por eso cualquier boton hace esa funcion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes bloquearlo por JS con el evento onclick, pero no te preocupes si no sabes JavaScript, HTLM nos deja hacer `onclick=""` a un elemento, en este caso a un botón y haciendo un `event.preventDefault()` nos bastaría para no enviar el formulario. Le dejo el código a continuación:

```html
<div class="contenedor">
<button onclick="event.preventDefault()" class="botonF11" id="opciones" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="left" data-content="OPCIONES" style="color: black;">
<span><i class="fas fa-tasks"></i></span>
</button>
<button onclick="event.preventDefault()" class="btn2 botonF2" id="abrircaja" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="left" data-content="ABRIR CAJA" style="color: black;">
<span><i class="fas fa-lock-open"></i></span>
</button>
<button onclick="event.preventDefault()" class="btn2 botonF3" id="cerrarcaja" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="left" data-content="CERRAR CAJA" style="color: black;">
<span><i class="fas fa-lock"></i></span>
</button>
<button onclick="event.preventDefault()" class="btn2 botonF4" id="es" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="left" data-content="ENTRADA/SALIDA" style="color: black;">
<span><i class="fas fa-dollar-sign"></i></span>
</button>
<button onclick="event.preventDefault()" class="btn2 botonF5" id="imprimir"  data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="left" data-content="IMPRIMIR" style="color: black;">
<span><i class="fas fa-print"></i></span>
</button>
</div>
```

Si lo quiere entero se lo dejaré aquí:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/eb7b540af7.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="views/modules/caja/reportecaja.php" >

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                    <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align: center;height: 10px;">DATOS DE SESION</h5>  
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label>CAJERO.:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <input type="hidden" name="nombre" value="<?php if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){echo $_SESSION['username'];}?>"/>
                        <label><?php if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){echo $_SESSION['username'];}?></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label>HORA INICIO:<?php if (isset($_SESSION['inicio'])){echo $_SESSION['inicio'];}?></label>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label>HORA FIN:<?php  date_default_timezone_set("America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires");$horaactual=date("H:i:s"); echo $horaactual;?></label>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label> Efectivo:</label>
                        <label id="subtotal"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label>Cambio:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="cambio" placeholder="QUEDA EN CAJA" id="cambio"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label>Total</label>
                        <label id="total"></label>
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div> 
</div>


<div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                 <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header" >
                    

                                                   
                        <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align: center;height: 10px;">LISTADO DE MOVIMIENTOS DEL TURNO</h5>  
                   </div>
                              <div class="card-body">
<div class="table-responsive" >                  
<table id="resumen" class="table table-hover">

<title>Comprobantes</title>
<thead class="thead-dark">

</thead><tfoot><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></tfoot>

<tbody>

</tbody>
</table></div> </div>
</div>  
</div>


<div class="contenedor">
<button onclick="event.preventDefault()" class="botonF11" id="opciones" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="left" data-content="OPCIONES" style="color: black;">
<span><i class="fas fa-tasks"></i></span>
</button>
<button onclick="event.preventDefault()" class="btn2 botonF2" id="abrircaja" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="left" data-content="ABRIR CAJA" style="color: black;">
<span><i class="fas fa-lock-open"></i></span>
</button>
<button onclick="event.preventDefault()" class="btn2 botonF3" id="cerrarcaja" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="left" data-content="CERRAR CAJA" style="color: black;">
<span><i class="fas fa-lock"></i></span>
</button>
<button onclick="event.preventDefault()" class="btn2 botonF4" id="es" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="left" data-content="ENTRADA/SALIDA" style="color: black;">
<span><i class="fas fa-dollar-sign"></i></span>
</button>
<button onclick="event.preventDefault()" class="btn2 botonF5" id="imprimir"  data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="left" data-content="IMPRIMIR" style="color: black;">
<span><i class="fas fa-print"></i></span>
</button>
</div>
</div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: El fallo está en que, al no declarar ningún botón de tipo "submit", cualquier botón interno del formulario va a hacer la acción del submit, la solución está en dejarlos fuera del formulario o hacerle un event.preventDefault()

Comment: Por cierto, le he metido BootStrap y Font-Awesome por cdn para que puedas visualizar lo que se vería en la web

Comment: Muchas gracias..funciona perfecto-.